# javascript getElementById outside function does not work

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, getelementbyid

I am relatively new to javascript and made this simple guess the number program.  My question is this:

Why does it only work if:

var myNumber = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

is defined within the function. I thought that if it was defined outside the function it will have "scope to b used within it?

Thank you for any help.

```html
<p> Enter your number 1-10 <input id="myNumber" type="text"> </p>
<button id="btn1">Go</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
    var myNumber = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;

    var number = parseInt(myNumber);

    var count = 1;
    var computerGuess = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    while (computerGuess !== number) {

      computerGuess = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      count++;
    }

    alert("you guessed it" + " in " + count + " guesses");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You let the computer guess the number the user entered instead of vice versa. You need to ask again but not in a while loop. Have the user click the button each time and get a new random number when the user guessed it or there has been no guess yet (on load). Make an `init` function and call it onload outside the onclick and again on correct guess

Comment: PS: To answer your question: If you put `var myNumber = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;` outside of the click event handler, it runs ONLY once, when the page loads. So when the user clicks, there is no value yet and there won't be any value

Comment: Oh yes, I get it now.  Thanks you for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

When you  will use document.getElementById in global scope it will return undefined if
the script is above the element which you wanna access. Because it can get element by id before it is created
Solution 1. Use all your script tags at last of all elements
Solution 2. use this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script>
var globalElm;
function start(){
    globalElm = document.getElementById('elm')
}
setTimeout(start,50);
</script>
<div id="elm"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its just explanation how you can create a gloabl variable having dom element using setTimeout

Comment: There is absolutely no need for timeout in this question unless op wants to put a limit in how fast the user needs to answer. You are just confusing a noob. Also it was not above the element